# JQUERY UI Accordion start collapsed

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I make the jquery UI accordion start collapsed when the form loads. Is there any javascript code for this?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

In your options specify:

```
{
  ...
  active: false,
  collapsible: true,
  ...
}
```

See documentation for [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active).

Comment: still working on JQuery 1.4.4 as of today, though Visual Studio 2010 throws a JScript error (no error in the UI) on IE 8

Comment: It still shows the accordion collapsing though, any way to speed that up at initial collapsing or prevent this? `animate: false` gets rid of the animation but for always, ideally only remove it for initial load.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Please disregard, I had .accordion wrapped in `$( function() {  } ); `, without that it works just fine and without animation at initial load, nice.

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to do the same thing. Using Jquery UI tabs. I wanted none to show with 5 tabs when you start.

using active: false showed the 5th tabs content. 
So I set tabs CSS to display:none; since it in-line changes display. Hope this helps someone!

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
    });
});
```

And in the style

```
#tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3, #tabs-4, #tabs-5{ 
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this code, as i was using a Dreamweaver Widget, the code that Topek didnt work for me
hope this helps,

```
jQuery("#jQueryUIAccordion").accordion({ 
        event: "click",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

To complete the [answer of topex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7947823/2530962), With Jquery UI 1.10.3 I had to set the 'collapsible' option before the 'active' one.

```js
$( ".accordion" ).accordion("option", { 
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

See the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

Comment: It still shows the accordion collapsing though, any way to speed that up at initial collapsing or prevent this? `animate: false` gets rid of the animation but for always, ideally only remove it for initial load.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Please disregard, I had .accordion wrapped in `$( function() {  } ); `, without that it works just fine and without animation at initial load, nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the wysiwyg "Properties" and the coding confuses, try putting a number in the "Active" box one more than your list of Sections. I have 12 sections and put "13" in there and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default jquery accordion it always display first panel content, you can disable it by using `active: false` attribute.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
    });
});
```

but it's default behavior is for all panels will be set to the height of the tallest panel.
so, for that you have to add `"heightStyle"` attribute.

```
heightStyle: "content",
```

so, each panel will be only as tall as its content.

Comment: It still shows the accordion collapsing though, any way to speed that up at initial collapsing or prevent this? `animate: false` gets rid of the animation but for always, ideally only remove it for initial load.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Please disregard, I had .accordion wrapped in `$( function() {  } ); `, without that it works just fine and without animation at initial load, nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the beginning of the panel group in your code, look for this

```
<div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

if you just remove the "in" it has the panel close when the page loads.