# Closing jQuery UI Accordions With CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Is there a way to force jQuery UI accordions closed with CSS until the page finishes loading? We're using it on a content management system, and each page takes a fare amount of time to load. The jQuery doesn't get triggured until the page is done loading, but which point, all the accordions are already expanded. They close once the page loads, but I feel like it's confusing to users to see a giant list of stuff come up and then disappear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947789/jquery-ui-accordion-start-collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option on the `.accordion({ ... })` call itself:

```
.accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true });
```

The `active: false` option makes it closed on creation and the `collapsible: true` option makes it so you can re-close it once you open it.

Comment: I beat him, with a reference to another question, but got converted to a comment as trivial.

Comment: But won't that still wait to fire until the page is done loading, since it's still in the `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Then just put it in a standard `$(function(){ });` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Rev, Yes, I think you're referring to FOUC or Flash of Unstyled Content.  You can follow many guides on how to get rid of that.  One naive (and not recommended) approach would be to hide everything and show it on `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

The options show how to initialize the accordion with all tabs closed. See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active This means the initialization code would be:

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the setup from the jQuery Accordion [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion), you can simply put `<div style="display: none">` on the content *div* below the *h3* headers. This will hide all the content in the accordion while the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like:

```
.accordion-body{
    display: none;
}
```

I guess that accordion will call $.show (or similar) somewhere, so you you will not need to worry displaying it again. Again, this is a guess, so in the case I'm wrong, you make it visible again using

```
$('.accordion-body').css('display', 'block');
$('#accordion').accordion();
```

But, if you are calling `.accordion()` on dom load, you can also try firing it earlier, using .load:

```
$('#accordion').load(function(){
    $(this).accordion();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

In your CSS, apply styles to the selector you're using to invoke the accordion:

```
.accordionSelector > div { display:none; }
```

Then change the `display` back to `block` after jQuery has loaded:

```
$(".accordionSelector").accordion({...}).children("div").css("display","block");
```