# jQueryAccordion Slider Assistance

Tags: jquery, accordion

Cheers Everyone -

I am trying to use the jquery accordion slider ( http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible )
but would like two options:

- Collapse Content
- No Auto Height

I am REALLY new to all this so I have no clue if its even possible to have two actions
in the same slider.

Easiest is if I could get something to copy and paste.  Please note that I cannot use any external styling.

Thx for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

just write both options with comma separated --> fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qFXXj/

but note: there is never a comma after the last one

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
```

**fiddle after updated edit**: http://jsfiddle.net/qFXXj/1/

Comment: One more quick thing ... when I reload the browser, the top slider is always open.  Is there something I should put within code to make it so the accordion starts out all closed?

Comment: @user there is an edit in the answer. could you please mark the answer as right and answered? if you google "jquery accordion start closed" the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947789/jquery-ui-accordion-start-collapsed also have a look at the fiddle after update http://jsfiddle.net/qFXXj/1/

Comment: @user I would appreciate that you mark the answer as answered