# How to open all items using jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I found the [open all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947789/jquery-ui-accordion-start-collapsed), But no use. Here I am using,

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
});
```

And [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUrqG/18/). I need to open all items when it is loaded first time.

Comment: the fiddle seems to be proper

Comment: sorry I need open all items.

Comment: I updated my question please check it once

Comment: Check this, [jQuery UI Accordion Expand/Collapse All](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all)

Comment: yes as per bios link, this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843418/jquery-ui-accordion-expand-collapse-all#answer-12903079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have some of your html added some `<div>`

and i guess you want this.
[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/RUrqG/24/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
$('#accordion .ui-accordion-content').show();
```